# passing object (which contains arraylist ) from one activity to another activity

Tags: android

Hi friends i am passing object (which contains arraylist ) from one activity to another activity
I read by serializable we could pass object by intent in activity 
but when i do i got a exception  in the last exception detail is mentioned , here is my code , by googling i read this , this is the problem of arraylist , that i am passing 
but how would i pass....

examples are given on net , we could only pass array list , or paas object , but 
my problem is i want to pass with in a single object , one array list and few other variables , currently i am using only single varrible , but it could be more ......

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Common_info implements Serializable{


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



private int numberOfFormats;
private ArrayList<Object> listOfFormats;



public int getNumberOfFormats() {
    return numberOfFormats;
}
public void setNumberOfFormats(int numberOfFormats) {
    this.numberOfFormats = numberOfFormats;
}
public ArrayList<Object> getListOfFormats() {
    return listOfFormats;
}
public void setListOfFormats(ArrayList<Object> listOfFormats) {
    this.listOfFormats = listOfFormats;
}


}
```

this is the part how i am calling

```
        Class<?> setClass;              
        Object obj_set_class;

         setClass = Class.forName(str_set_class_name_with_full_path);               
         obj_set_class = setClass.newInstance();



        Object obj_arr_parameters[] = {mode,set_code};
        Class<?> class_arr_Parameters_type[] = new Class[obj_arr_parameters.length];

          for (int i = 0; i < obj_arr_parameters.length; i++) {
                if (obj_arr_parameters[i] instanceof Integer) {

                    class_arr_Parameters_type[i] = Integer.TYPE;

                } else if (obj_arr_parameters[i] instanceof String) {

                    class_arr_Parameters_type[i] = String.class;

                }/*else if (obj_arr_parameters[i] instanceof EditText) {

                    class_arr_Parameters_type[i] = EditText.class;
                }*/

            }
        Method thisMethod = setClass.getDeclaredMethod("getTestInfo", class_arr_Parameters_type);
        Common_info obj_Common_info =   (Common_info) thisMethod.invoke(obj_set_class, obj_arr_parameters);

        System.out.println("number of uis " +obj_Common_info.getNumberOfFormats());

        Intent intent = new Intent(this,ActStartTest2.class);
        intent.putExtra("student_id", student_id);
        intent.putExtra("student_name", student_name);
        intent.putExtra("set_code", set_code);
        intent.putExtra("set_common_info", obj_Common_info);
        //intent.putExtra("mode", CConstants.PRACTICE_MODE);
        startActivity(intent);
```

EXception Details

```
    09-05 08:15:56.308: W/System.err(7893): java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.cuelearn.cuemath_k8.beans.Common_info)
09-05 08:15:56.318: W/System.err(7893):     at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1316)
09-05 08:15:56.318: W/System.err(7893):     at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1264)
09-05 08:15:56.318: W/System.err(7893):     at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:618)
09-05 08:15:56.318: W/System.err(7893):     at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1692)
09-05 08:15:56.328: W/System.err(7893):     at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:636)
09-05 08:15:56.328: W/System.err(7893):     at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:7013)
09-05 08:15:56.328: W/System.err(7893):     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2076)
09-05 08:15:56.328: W/System.err(7893):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1419)
09-05 08:15:56.328: W/System.err(7893):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
09-05 08:15:56.328: W/System.err(7893):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
09-05 08:15:56.328: W/System.err(7893):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
09-05 08:15:56.328: W/System.err(7893):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
09-05 08:15:56.328: W/System.err(7893):     at com.cuelearn.cuemath_k8.act.ActHomeScreen.startTest(ActHomeScreen.java:212)
09-05 08:15:56.338: W/System.err(7893):     at com.cuelearn.cuemath_k8.act.ActHomeScreen.onSelectedConcept(ActHomeScreen.java:140)
09-05 08:15:56.338: W/System.err(7893):     at com.cuelearn.cuemath_k8.ui_files.frag_general.FragConceptsList.onClick(FragConceptsList.java:76)
09-05 08:15:56.338: W/System.err(7893):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
09-05 08:15:56.338: W/System.err(7893):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
09-05 08:15:56.338: W/System.err(7893):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-05 08:15:56.338: W/System.err(7893):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-05 08:15:56.338: W/System.err(7893):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-05 08:15:56.338: W/System.err(7893):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
09-05 08:15:56.358: W/System.err(7893):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-05 08:15:56.358: W/System.err(7893):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-05 08:15:56.368: W/System.err(7893):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
09-05 08:15:56.368: W/System.err(7893):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
09-05 08:15:56.368: W/System.err(7893):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-05 08:15:56.378: W/System.err(7893): Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.cuelearn.cuemath_k8.ui_files.frag_questions.Frag_Ui_Type_1
09-05 08:15:56.378: W/System.err(7893):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1364)
09-05 08:15:56.378: W/System.err(7893):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
09-05 08:15:56.378: W/System.err(7893):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
09-05 08:15:56.378: W/System.err(7893):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
09-05 08:15:56.378: W/System.err(7893):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:979)
09-05 08:15:56.378: W/System.err(7893):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:368)
09-05 08:15:56.378: W/System.err(7893):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1074)
09-05 08:15:56.378: W/System.err(7893):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1404)
09-05 08:15:56.378: W/System.err(7893):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
09-05 08:15:56.378: W/System.err(7893):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
09-05 08:15:56.398: W/System.err(7893):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
09-05 08:15:56.398: W/System.err(7893):     at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:648)
09-05 08:15:56.398: W/System.err(7893):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-05 08:15:56.398: W/System.err(7893):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-05 08:15:56.398: W/System.err(7893):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1053)
09-05 08:15:56.408: W/System.err(7893):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1404)
09-05 08:15:56.408: W/System.err(7893):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
09-05 08:15:56.408: W/System.err(7893):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
09-05 08:15:56.408: W/System.err(7893):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
09-05 08:15:56.408: W/System.err(7893):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:979)
09-05 08:15:56.408: W/System.err(7893):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:368)
09-05 08:15:56.408: W/System.err(7893):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1074)
09-05 08:15:56.408: W/System.err(7893):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1404)
09-05 08:15:56.408: W/System.err(7893):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
09-05 08:15:56.408: W/System.err(7893):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
09-05 08:15:56.418: W/System.err(7893):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
09-05 08:15:56.418: W/System.err(7893):     at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1311)
09-05 08:15:56.418: W/System.err(7893):     ... 25 more
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,ActStartTest2.class);
intent.putExtra("student_id", student_id);
intent.putExtra("student_name", student_name);
intent.putExtra("set_code", set_code);
intent.putExtra("set_common_info", obj_Common_info);  
startActivity(intent);
```

In class ActStartTest2 try this

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Common_info  com_Info = (Common_info)i.getSerializableExtra("set_common_info");
```

Comment: I am trying same      Common_info common_info = (Common_info) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("set_common_info");

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace mentions `java.io.NotSerializableException: com.cuelearn.cuemath_k8.ui_files.frag_questions.Frag_Ui_Type_1` - which means you are referencing this (non-serializable) class somewhere down the hierarchy of the object you are trying to put in your Parcel (probably obj_common_info, but I am not sure).

Just as a side note - in Android it is recommended to use Parcels instead of Serializable classes. True that it might require more coding, but it is said to be faster. Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html).